# Save State Between Route Transitions in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there an acceptable way to save state between routes in an EmberJS application?  For example, I have an Infinite Scroller implemented as an `ArrayController` with pages of content retrieved from the server as the user scrolls.  When the user clicks on one of these results I would like to transition to a dedicated "Details" route.

So far so good, but I would also like them to be able to click "back" on their browser, or a back link on the website to go back to the previous route in the state it was in when they left.  What is the best way to accomplish this sort of thing within Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the model of the `ArrayController` as you scroll (not from a route callback function as `model`) , say for a route called `pages`, then by clicking back after visiting a resource like `pages/1` the `ArrayController` should have the last set model and present the last viewed results.

For example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ElADOdeC/1#/pages

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('pages');
  this.route('page',{path:'/pages/:page_id'});
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    this.transitionTo('pages');
  }
});

App.PagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  index:0,
  pages:function(){
    return pagesData.slice(this.get('index'),this.get('index')+2);
  }.property('index'),
  actions:{
    next:function(){
      if(this.get('index')==pagesData.length-1){
        this.set('index',0);
      }else{
        this.set('index',this.get('index')+1);
      }
    }
  }
});

App.PageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(params){
    return pagesData[params.page_id];
  }
});

App.Page = Ember.Object.extend({
  id:null,
  pageContent:"This is the content of this page"
});

var pagesData = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  pagesData.pushObject(App.Page.create({id:i}));
}
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    nothing here
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="pages">
    Pages
    <br/>
    {{#each page in pages}}
    {{page.id}}
    <br/>
    {{page.pageContent}}
    <br/>
    {{#link-to 'page' page}}details{{/link-to}}
    <br/>
    <hr>
    <br/>
    {{/each}}
    <button {{action "next"}}>next</button>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="page">
    <b>This is page</b> {{id}} <br/>
    <b>with content:</b></br>
    {{pageContent}}
  </script>
```

Comment: if this is true I will feel foolish for having asked, but I will definitely test this out to see for sure!

Comment: @MattBaker i will try to provide an example asap.

Comment: @MattBaker updated the answer with an example, hope it helps.

Comment: Great example, thank you.  What does this mean for the `route`'s `model` call?  Should I avoid populating Model, is model not called for "back" actions, or should I only set `controller`'s content if it isn't an empty array?

Comment: @MattBaker it is perfectly valid to populate the model, however the route's model call will be called whenever you select `back`. So yes if you choose to use that, care must be taken to set the model properly each time by checking some properties of the `arraycontroller`.

Comment: @MattBaker here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ugIxIrI/1#/pages you can find the same example using the `model` of `arraycontroller`. There might be a better approach of implementing this by using the route's `model` function, but here the code got a little messy trying to handle the `next` event, `index` and refreshing the `model` in two different places, the `route` and `arraycontroller`.

Comment: Finally got to the point where I needed to do this, and it works as expected.  I don't refresh unless the controller's content is empty or the model's ID is different than the one currently on the Controller.  The only other thing that was tricky was figuring out how to restore the scroll location, which I also managed to figure out.  Thanks!